# Why does re.match/re.search work, but re.findall doesn't work?

Tags: python, regex

I use re.match to find the string like this:

```
print(re.match('''#include(\s)?".*"''', '''#include "my.h"'''))
```

then I got the result like this:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 15), match='#include "my.h"'>
```

and then I replace match function:

```
print(re.findall('''#include(\s)?".*"''', '''#include "my.h"'''))
```

the result is:

```
[' ']
```

I was confused, why dosen't `re.findall` return the matched string? What's wrong with my regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help(re.findall)`:

> Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.
>
> If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return a
>   list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more
>   than one group.
>
> Empty matches are included in the result.

Your parenthesized bit, `(\s)`, is a capturing group, so `re.findall` returns a list of the captures. There’s only one capturing group, so each item in the list is just a string, rather than a tuple.

You can make the group non-capturing using `?:`, i.e. `(?:\s)?`. That isn’t very useful at that point, though, since it’s equivalent to just `\s?`. For more flexibility – e.g. if you ever need to capture more than one part – `re.finditer` is probably the best way to go:

```
for m in re.finditer(r'#include\s*"(.*?)"', '#include "my.h"'):
    print('Included %s using %s' % (m.group(1), m.group(0)))
```